# Injecting cache to a module

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I am trying to inject cache to a module using module.config.php with no luck. My module.config.php looks like this

```
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'AssetLoader\Module' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'cache'       => 'Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

and in my Module.php

```
public function setCache(\Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem $cache)
{
    die(__FUNCTION__);
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

But nothing happens. I expect script to die but for some reason this function is never executed. I am sure I am doing something wrong but can someone explain how to inject a cache (or any other object in that matter) to the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered on Zend mailing list now.
[See here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-Injecting-cache-to-a-module-td4386631.html)

Matthew pointed out that Module classes weren't pulled out from locator, so you can't use DI to inject resources to the modules. See the link to see how it's done.